# Bazel: add executable to PATH

Tags: python, bazel

I am having trouble with installing python in my Bazel build. I tried following different approaches, starting with the official bazel_rules documentation, but I get the error `/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: No such file or directory`. I have tried several approaches with downloading the python installation as part of the build and registering them as a toolchain, but I still get the same error. Looking at the `PATH` env variable inside the build I see that the directory where my python installation is is not included in it, but some non-existent directory is. This lead me to think that I could modify `PATH` myself to include my actual python folder. However, I couldn't find a way to set environment variables inside a `repository_rule`. Is there a way to do that? Am I on the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rely on the python downloaded in your repository_rule. You need a python installation inside your system(i.e. you can run `python3` in your terminal)

> After registration, your Python targets will use the toolchain's interpreter during execution, but a system-installed interpreter is still used to 'bootstrap' Python targets (see #691).

See https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python